# PyTorch: passing numpy array for weight initialization

Tags: python, numpy, initialization, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I'd like to initialize the parameters of RNN with np arrays.

In the following example, I want to pass `w` to the parameters of `rnn`. I know pytorch provides many initialization methods like Xavier, uniform, etc., but is there way to initialize the parameters by passing numpy arrays?

```
import numpy as np
import torch as nn
rng = np.random.RandomState(313)
w = rng.randn(input_size, hidden_size).astype(np.float32)

rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's note that `nn.RNN` has more than one weight variable, c.f. the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.RNN):

> Variables:
>
> - `weight_ih_l[k]` – the learnable input-hidden weights of the `k`-th layer, of shape `(hidden_size * input_size)` for `k = 0`. Otherwise,
>     the shape is `(hidden_size * hidden_size)`
> - `weight_hh_l[k]` – the learnable hidden-hidden weights of the `k`-th layer, of shape `(hidden_size * hidden_size)`
> - `bias_ih_l[k]` – the learnable input-hidden bias of the `k`-th layer, of shape `(hidden_size)`
> - `bias_hh_l[k]` – the learnable hidden-hidden bias of the `k`-th layer, of shape `(hidden_size)`

Now, each of these variables ([`Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Parameter) instances) are attributes of your `nn.RNN` instance. You can access them, and edit them, two ways, as show below:

- **Solution 1: Accessing all the RNN `Parameter` attributes by name (`rnn.weight_hh_lK`, `rnn.weight_ih_lK`, etc.):**

```python
import torch
from torch import nn
import numpy as np

input_size, hidden_size, num_layers = 3, 4, 2
use_bias = True
rng = np.random.RandomState(313)

rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, bias=use_bias)

def set_nn_parameter_data(layer, parameter_name, new_data):
    param = getattr(layer, parameter_name)
    param.data = new_data

for i in range(num_layers):
    weights_hh_layer_i = rng.randn(hidden_size, hidden_size).astype(np.float32)
    weights_ih_layer_i = rng.randn(hidden_size, hidden_size).astype(np.float32)
    set_nn_parameter_data(rnn, "weight_hh_l{}".format(i), 
                          torch.from_numpy(weights_hh_layer_i))
    set_nn_parameter_data(rnn, "weight_ih_l{}".format(i), 
                          torch.from_numpy(weights_ih_layer_i))

    if use_bias:
        bias_hh_layer_i = rng.randn(hidden_size).astype(np.float32)
        bias_ih_layer_i = rng.randn(hidden_size).astype(np.float32)
        set_nn_parameter_data(rnn, "bias_hh_l{}".format(i), 
                              torch.from_numpy(bias_hh_layer_i))
        set_nn_parameter_data(rnn, "bias_ih_l{}".format(i), 
                              torch.from_numpy(bias_ih_layer_i))
```

- **Solution 2: Accessing all the RNN `Parameter` attributes through `rnn.all_weights` list attribute:**

```python
import torch
from torch import nn
import numpy as np

input_size, hidden_size, num_layers = 3, 4, 2
use_bias = True
rng = np.random.RandomState(313)

rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, bias=use_bias)

for i in range(num_layers):
    weights_hh_layer_i = rng.randn(hidden_size, hidden_size).astype(np.float32)
    weights_ih_layer_i = rng.randn(hidden_size, hidden_size).astype(np.float32)
    rnn.all_weights[i][0].data = torch.from_numpy(weights_ih_layer_i)
    rnn.all_weights[i][1].data = torch.from_numpy(weights_hh_layer_i)

    if use_bias:
        bias_hh_layer_i = rng.randn(hidden_size).astype(np.float32)
        bias_ih_layer_i = rng.randn(hidden_size).astype(np.float32)
        rnn.all_weights[i][2].data = torch.from_numpy(bias_ih_layer_i)
        rnn.all_weights[i][3].data = torch.from_numpy(bias_hh_layer_i)
```

Comment: What would this be like for GRU/LSTM?

Answer (score 2):

As a detailed answer is provided, I just to add one more sentence. The parameters of an `nn.Module` are Tensors (previously, it used to be autograd variables, [which is deperecated in Pytorch 0.4](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated)). So, essentially you need to use the `torch.from_numpy()` method to convert the Numpy array to Tensor and then use them to initialize the `nn.Module` parameters.