# Same random seed for Numpy and PyTorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, random-seed

I am trying to compare my functions in vanilla Python/Numpy to those of PyTorch. For that I would like to set the seed of both to make the results comparable.

Is it possible to set the seed for numpy like `np.random.seed(x)` and PyTorch like `torch.manual_seed(x)` so that both produce the same random numbers?

Right now, with the same `x` value `np.random.uniform(0, 1)` and `torch.rand(1)` produce different outputs.

Comment: They use different random number generators and distributions, you can't expect them to give exactly the same sequence with the same seed.

Comment: Yes, but I am asking if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: Depends on your code, I suspect you can monkey patch numpy to use pytorch random (providing the same API), then numpy calls would produce the same numbers.

Comment: Other solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628607/pytorch-passing-numpy-array-for-weight-initialization

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of this solution?

Instead of

```py
np.random.seed(0)

np.random.rand(0, 1)
```

you could use

```py
torch.manual_seed(0) 

torch.rand(1).numpy()
```

That way, you will have the same random numbers between PyTorch and NumPy, but still as a NumPy array if you want...