# AttributeError: ‘RNN’ object has no attribute ‘weight_hh_l’

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I want to change weights on my own

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def init(self):
        super(Net, self).init()
        self.F = torch.randint(0,255,(len(train_dataset),image_size))
        self.I =torch.ones(image_size,image_size)
        self.w = 0.00001
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(image_size,len(train_dataset),1,‘relu’)
        self.rnn.weight_hh_l[0] = torch.t(self.F)
        self.rnn.weight_ih_l[0] = (self.I - (self.w * torch.mm(torch.t(self.F),self.F)))
```

And have error

```
AttributeError: 'RNN' object has no attribute 'weight_hh_l'
```

What I’m doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site :) it looks like `weight_hh_l` is not a classical attribute that you can set this way (see [the source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py)). Maybe have a look at the `__setstate__` method? Pretty hacky but it could work. I don't know enough myself to formulate a proper answer.

Comment: Here is answer the my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628607/pytorch-passing-numpy-array-for-weight-initialization/51630378[link][1]

Comment: Great! Mind if I mark this question as a duplicate then?

Comment: Yes, sure :) Thank you for help